# Is it possible to add event listener using PHP?

Tags: php, dom-events, smarty

I'm creating a survey form using Smarty templates in which I want to attach an event with radio buttons of a particular question such that it pops-up a message when any one of them is clicked.

So I want to add a click/change event listener on them but don't know how to do it using PHP. As I do not know the radio button id in advance (they are generated on the fly), I'm not sure if I can use JavaScript here.
Any solutions/suggestions?

Google search returns all sort of answers for adding event listeners for Android and JavaScript which are of no use!

Comment: Why can't you generate parts of the JavaScript server-side via PHP?

Comment: How will you find the radio button if you don't know the id?

Comment: I know the question (when I fetch it from db) whose radio button is to be added with pop-up... in Smarty, the display is handled using templates which is the place where the code creates the id for the radio button. Although I can try to use the code-generation logic inside php.
Jack's suggestion sounds looks like a possibile option, searching more on that

Comment: Is your question how to add a listener to a checkbox that you don't know its id? Can you give the checkbox a CSS class 'my-cb' and use jQuery? `$('input.my-cb').change(function(){...})`

Comment: hmm... that may be possible. I'll have to check and revert back on that. Thnx for the idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a class to the radio buttons, then using JavaScript/JQuery, you could add event listeners to the inputs as needed.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="clickyradio" />
<input type="radio" class="clickyradio" />
<input type="radio" class="clickyradio" />
```

now in the file myjsfile.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.clickyradio').click(function() {
      // whatever you want to happen when it gets clicked
      // "this" keyword will refer to the input element that got clicked

   });
});
```

if you need the click to communicate something to the server, put an ajax call within the click event handler.

Comment: Thnx for the code! I had the issue since I was using an existing system to build upon... did some hunting and ugly hacks to incorporate the idea... and there it was!!! Working as needed :)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you'll get to a php event listener is calling some specific php functionality via ajax, after a javascript event has fired. that request is technically *attached* to the chain of events (callbacks) from the client side.

but php doesn't do that because its not client side.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't listen for the radio button, as all the code is done on the server side, while the radio button will be clicked on the client side.  You will almost certainly have to use JavaScript.  If you are not very comfortable with JS, I would recomend checking out jQuery.  It is very user friendly, and quick to learn IMHO.  With that you can listen for the raido button to be clicked, then pass the information back to the PHP script via AJAX.  I would give you a better example, but without knowing your code it is difficult to illustrate it.

Comment: I've worked with JS, so that's not a issue. I wasn't aware that I can create JS within PHP as suggested by Jack in comments above, so now searching how to do that. I think it will solve my prob. If you have a code to illustrate that, it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, you just want to use php to write your javascript. You can do this one of two ways, by writing it in the file OR by pointing your script to the php file.

If you choose the latter,[this site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml)

discusses how to set up the file. If you do it in the document, you'd just do something like

```
    <?php

   echo "<script>";

   if($radio_button == 'blah'){
      echo "document.getElementById('$radio_button')";//bind your event here
   }
   echo "</script>";
```

Make sense? Calling the php file in the javascript command is probably tidier, but both ways work.